# can't write IP to text file without formatting issues

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble reading an IP from a text file and properly writing it to another text file. It shows the written IP in the file as: "ÿþ1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 1 1 0 . 4"

```
#Read the first line for the IP
def get_server_ip
  File.open("d:\\ip_addr.txt") do |line|
    a = line.readline()
    b =  a.to_s
  end
  end

#append the ip to file2
def append_ip
  FileUtils.cp('file1.txt', 'file2.txt')
  file_names = ['file2.txt']
  file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  b = get_server_ip
  new_contents = text.gsub('ip_here', b)
  File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
  end
  end
```

I've tried .strip and .delete(' ') with no luck. Can anyone see the issue?

Thank you

Comment: The file seems to be generated with Notepad on Windows. It is encoded, most probably, as `UTF-16LE` (the spaces between the printable characters are NULL characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file was generated with Notepad on Windows. It is encoded as [`UTF-16LE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes).

The first two bytes in the file have the codes [`0xFF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)#HTML) and [`0xFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)); this is the [Bytes Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) of `UTF-16LE`.

Each character is encoded on 2 bytes (16 bits), the least significant byte first (Less Endian order).
The spaces between the printable characters in the output are, in fact [`NUL` characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (characters with code `0`).

What you can do (apart from converting the file to a more decent format like `UTF-8` or even `ISO-8859-1`) is to pass `'rb:BOM|UTF-16LE'` as the second argument of [`File#open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html#method-c-open).

- `r` tells `File#open` to open the file in read-only mode (which is also does by default);
- `b` means "binary mode"; it is required by `BOM|UTF-16`;
- `:BOM|UTF-16LE` tells Ruby to read and ignore the `BOM` if it is present in the file and to expect the rest of the file being encoded as `UTF16-LE`.

---

If you can, I recommend you to convert the file encoding using a decent editor (even Notepad can be used) to `UTF-8` or `ISO-8859-1` and all these problems vanish.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!